# Removable desk attachment

Tags: desk

**Background**

I try to build an attachment for my desk. The attachment will be a place to put my joystick/throttle while gaming. This attachment needs to be easily removable (many times), preferably without tightening/loosening any screws. The permanent part on the desk needs to be very flat, as I need the room for my legs in normal operation.

**Requirements**

- low profile
- easy attachment/detachment
- somewhat stress resistant (I should be able to push on it, but not sit on it)
- the attachment needs to be tight (little to no wiggle)

**My ideas**

After some quick brainstorming I came up with the idea to use a cap rail (normally used in electrical engineering), as they are cheap, have a low profile and are durable (steel, brass). Attachment/detachment would be easy, as I could just slide the attachment on the rail and that would be it (pulling on the attachment is not an issue).

The problem now is the part on the attachment, which needs to slide over the rail. I did some research and did not find any "counter rail" to the cap rail (I assume because there is no need for it if you use it for its purpose).

I thought I could probably just use screws, but it would be a pain to screw them in correctly, to get a tight fit.

I also thought of rails you put in drawers, but they are either not removable, too loose or to high profile and most importantly they are made to move around.

**Question**

Does anyone know the proper term to find a "cap rail counter rail" or has some DIY hack to build one?

Or is there a good alternative to the cap rail?

Comment: why don't you attach a fold-down leaf on the side of the desk?

Comment: @jsotola I am not sure what you mean. But I don't have space on the side of my desk. And I can't fold it underneath, because I need the room for my legs